# Can I use umlaut in mssql key?

Tags: sql-server, key

We have the following problem with MSSQL Server 2008:
an entity declares a combined key consisting of a logon name and a system id, like so

```
<properties name="uk1" unique="true">
  <property name="logonName" column="LOGON_NAME" insert="false" update="false"/>
  <many-to-one name="sapSystem" column="SYSTEM_ID" insert="false" update="false"/>
</properties>
```

If the logon name contains an umlaut, e.g. one account with 'Weiss' and another one with 'Weiß', the SQL server throws an constraint exception.
Is there a restriction as to what the content of a key can be?
Are there any other settings  I can use to make this work correctly?

Comment: You'd usually deal with this (if you think it's a good idea - most people don't think having logins that only differ by *case* make much sense, and I'd usually put ss vs ß in the same category) by changing the collation being used. Unfortunately, I don't recognize (beyond XML) what technology you're using there in your code, so cannot provide any help on how to set an appropriate collation with your technology.

Comment: I don't like it myself, you're right. But unfortunately SAP allows it and that is, what we have to deal with... The snippet is from Hibernate which we use to load data from an SAP system into an MSSQL db.